# Farseer Circle Body Problems, Please help!

Tags: c#, 2d, farseer-physics-engine

I have created a circle body class, but in game my player body just passes through it. the circle will not move, only rotate.

however when i create the circle body just straight up, raw in the game1 load content method, without using a personalised class, it works. so im thinking i have done something wrong but i cant for the life of me spot it.

here are the two different implementations, the first is the class and its instance in the game1 class, THAT doesn't want to move the circle around or collide properly, the second is the classless implementation directly in the load content method of the game1 class.

```
    class CircleBody
{
    Texture2D Texture;
    Vector2 Origin;
    Vector2 Position;
    public Body Circle;

    public CircleBody(Texture2D texture, Vector2 position, World world)
    {
        this.Texture = texture;
        this.Origin = new Vector2(this.Texture.Width / 2f, this.Texture.Height / 2f);
        this.Position = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(position.X), ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(position.Y));
        Circle = BodyFactory.CreateCircle(world, ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(56 / 2), 1f, this.Position);
        Circle.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
        Circle.Restitution = 0.3f;
        Circle.Friction = 0.5f;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(this.Texture, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(this.Position), null, Color.White, this.Circle.Rotation,
            this.Origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
```

here is the above class instanced and implemented in the game1 class:

Variables:

```
        CircleBody CircleBody;
        Texture2D CircleTexture;
```

Load Content Method:

```
    CircleTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Player");
    CircleBody = new CircleBody(CircleTexture, new Vector2(400, 300), world);
```

Drawing:

```
    CircleBody.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

it just doesn't work :(,

HOWEVER it works perfectly when I create it in a different way, as in not through my own class, but raw within the game1 class. here is the code.

Variables:

```
     Texture2D playerTex;
     Vector2 playerOrigin;
     Body player;
```

LoadContent Method

```
    playerTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Player"); // 
    playerOrigin = new Vector2(playerTex.Width / 2f, playerTex.Height / 2f);
    /* Circle */
     Convert screen center from pixels to meters
    Vector2 playerPosition = ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(screenCenter); 
     Create the player fixture
    player = BodyFactory.CreateCircle(world, ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(56 / 2), 1f, playerPosition);
    player.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
    player.Restitution = 0.3f;
    player.Friction = 0.5f;
```

Drawing:

```
   spriteBatch.Draw(playerTex, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(player.Position), null, Color.White, player.Rotation,
                playerOrigin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

The first method through the class is obviously the cleaner and perfect way i want to implement the creation of a circle based body sprite combination, but i dont understand why the sprite is not moving, or collidable or seemingly alive in the simulation.

and i really dont see why it works raw in game1 class.

i really hope you can help!!! im sooooo stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Vector2 Position;
```

To this:

```
Vector2 Position { get { return Circle.Position; } set { Circle.Position = value; } }
```

And then pass your `new Vector2` directly into `BodyFactory.CreateCircle`.

---

What is happening here is that `Vector2` is a "value type" and not a "reference type".

When you pass a value type (as you do to the `BodyFactory.CreateCircle`), it takes a *copy* of that value type, leaving the original alone. So *your* `Position` variable is not being modified when the Farseer body moves.

(Whereas, if `Vector2` were a reference type, then it is the *reference* that gets copied - not the object instance the reference refers to. So then you might expect the `Body` class to keep your object instance updated - although the exact behaviour would be defined by `Body`.)

In this case, the simplest work-around would be to change `Position` from being a variable, to a property that simply access the correct `Vector2` out of the `Body` class.

An alternative might be just access `Circle.Position` directly.

Comment: Thank you so much. i dont know why i didn;t notice that but im certainly glad you did and coudl help m.